# Utilising an OO PHP approach with Vue.js

Tags: php, vue.js, web-applications, vuejs2

I have a bit of experiences using PHP frameworks like Laravel to act as a backend API to a Vue.js frontend. However I am current involved in a project at work which is using a purely plain PHP backend, without an MVC approach.

I am producing a small subsection which follows a few steps.

- Take user uploaded CSV from a from
- Checks it using regex to make sure all the information is current formatted.
- Returns all valid and failed lines back to the screen.
- After the user confirms at this stage, it will then validate the data against existing database records.
- It will return all valid and invalid lines again in relation to what currently exists in the database.
- The user will then be able to submit all of the files to be uploaded to the database.

So far I have the Vue frontend constructed and PHP scripts to interact with the class which handles the data format, validation and upload.

I'm struggling to visualise how to receive the data from the PHP side back into my application, as I will be moving data between the two a few times. I know I could use axios to call different PHP files designed to interact with certain areas of the class. However to me this seems like a very poor way to implement such functionality. I'm wondering if there is any way I can directly call elements of the class using something like axios, where it can send and retrieve the response.

I wondering if anyone can sort with any guidance. Or point me in the direction of any examples or guides that will help me clarify this functionality. As I've been scratching my help trying to think of ways to implement this successfully. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I recommend following a MVC architecture to achieve what you're looking for. You can route the request to these functions inside of the classes by using a MVC framework like like Lumen from Laravel. This question is a bit broad as well since there really is no one right answer.

Comment: I genuinely don't see any reason not to validate the valid rows you found from #2 against the database immediately so you can return all validation at the same time. This seems like bad UX.

Comment: To echo the first to responses, Laravel is what you want instead of writing it yourself.  The Laravel Validator and its MVC architecture get you most of the way there.  You can even write laravel validator to validate against the database.  Though @Ohgodwhy make a good point on the bad multistep/wizard validation logic or UX against bulk data, may be too slow.  You could bulk insert into staging table then you can manipulate everything server-side based on client-side approval.